# Raspberry Pi etc/apt/sources.list is missing

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I might have removed etc/apt/sources.list by accident and now everytime I try to install something on my Raspberry Pi I get the following error message

Package phpmyadmin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'phpmyadmin' has no installation candidate

How can I get the /etc/apt/sources.list file back

Answer (score 1):

First, check out if you have really deleted it, or if you have a copy of the sources file, such as /etc/apt/sources.list.save (some programs create such a copies automatically when used). Run the following code to find possible copies:

```
ls /etc/apt/ | grep -ie "sources.list"
```

If you can't find a copy there, then you will have to recreate the sources file. To do so, it would depend on the Linux distribution you run -- do a search for "sources.list myLinuxDistribution" and see what comes up. For Debian 8, it could be something like this:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Once you find a suitable sources.list code, you may run your favorite text editor (ex: `gksudo leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list`), paste the sources.list content there and then save the new file.

Answer (score 0):

The standard /etc/apt/sources.list for Raspbian Jessie Lite looks like this:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

I think there are no other entries needed for phpmyadmin.

In addition there is a file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list that looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
```

The following is a complete list of all files in /etc/apt inclusive file permission settings. I did not include empty directories.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -alR /etc/apt
/etc/apt:
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 88 root root 4096 Dec 16 20:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16 20:10 apt.conf.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   99 Nov 25 17:28 listchanges.conf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr  2  2016 preferences.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  234 Nov 25 17:22 sources.list
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:55 sources.list.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2424 Nov 25 17:22 trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1233 Nov 25 17:22 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr  2  2016 trusted.gpg.d

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d:
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 16 20:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:28 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  643 Apr  2  2016 01autoremove
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  981 Nov 25 17:24 01autoremove-kernels
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  141 Oct 12  2014 20listchanges
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  161 Nov 25 17:30 50raspi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  182 Mar 19  2015 70debconf

/etc/apt/sources.list.d:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:28 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Nov 25 17:55 raspi.list
```